# Set a default value to jquery variable

Tags: jquery

I want to set a default value to a variable.

When the body loads it runs a function which needs the variable to get the data.
The form will do the same onchange but the form elements will be hidden and added only if the user wants to see the filter options

My current code is

```
var grade = document.getElementById('grade').value;
```

If the id grade isnt available on the first load of the i want the grade to default to 0

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it should default it to zero.

```
var grade = document.getElementById('grade') == null ? 0 : document.getElementById('grade').value;
```

Comment: That will give you an error: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null"

Comment: That should do it, but this feels so unnatural. I really like it better with jQuery: `var grade = $('#grade').val() || 0`

Comment: @landons that's not jQuery-specific syntax. It's just an (ab)use of the lazy or.

Comment: @JanDvorak I should have said "Javascript framework." To that extent, all frameworks are "(ab)use[s] of the lazy"

Comment: @landons `||` is what is meant by "lazy or", or "short-circuiting or"

Comment: This is a most pointless discussion we're attempting to have here ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var grade = 0;
var grade_field = document.getElementById('grade');
if (grade_field)
{
    grade = grade_field.value;
}
```